# GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz ERROR 403: Forbidden Google Collab

Tags: google-colaboratory, wget, gensim, word2vec, http-status-code-403

Below is the code in a cell in google collab:

```
!wget -P /root/input -c "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
EMBEDDING_FILE = '/root/input/GoogleNews-vectors.negative300.bin.gz'
word2vec = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(EMBEDDING_FILE, binary=True)
```

After running the cell it shows an error which is:

> --2022-09-25 00:58:15--  https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz
> Resolving s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)... 52.216.85.117
> Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.85.117|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
> 2022-09-25 00:58:15 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Why is it showing this issue? Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The web server is returning 403. The request is forbidden. Talk to whoever is running the server.

Comment: A youtube video did the same thing. And that code ran without any error. Here is the video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzzeAzI1Apw&t=257s

Answer (score 1):

When I try to visit https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz from my web browser, I also get a 403 'Access Denied'.

So it simply looks like those who manage that resource have blocked access, perhaps because they did not intend it to be a free source for that file on demand. (If many people are casually downloading that ~3.5GB file when needed, it could be racking up noticeable bandwidth fees for the hoster.)

I suggest you find the same file elsewhere, and manually download it in a way that once it succeed, you won't have to redundantly hit the source server again, because you'll keep a persistent local copy.